# How do I DRY the callback functions in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to **DRY** before_create and  before_update,

How could I achieve this in **active_admin**

## Current snippet

```
   before_create do |product|
    categories = []
    params["product"]["category_ids"].reject{ |c| c.empty? }.each do |category|
      categories << Category.find_by_id(category.to_i).name
    end
    product.category_list = categories
   end

   before_update do |product|
    categories = []
    params["product"]["category_ids"].reject{ |c| c.empty? }.each do |category|
      categories << Category.find_by_id(category.to_i).name
    end
    product.category_list = categories
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

Callback in ActiveAdmin work much like ActiveSupport callbacks: they accept either a block or a symbol (of a method name). In this case that method has to be defined on the controller. So you could do something along the lines:

```
controller do 
  def set_categories
    categories = []
    params["product"]["category_ids"].reject{ |c| c.empty? }.each do |category|
      categories << Category.find_by_id(category.to_i).name
    end
    product.category_list = categories
  end
end

before_create :set_categories
before_update :set_categories
```